# Solving a probability mass function for unknown values

Tags: probability

I am tasked with the following:

Given a variable, $X$, has a probability mass functions of the form $f(x) = x/c$, where $x = 1, 2, 3, ..., n$, for some constant $c$.

Find $c$.

If there was no $,...,n$ and some fixed constant this is trivial. In fact I am told this is trivial to solve but I do not see where to begin given there is no defined stopping point, just $n$.

Comment: Isn't $n$ the "defined stopping point"?

Comment: Hint: triangle numbers.

Comment: If $x$ is increasing by 1 each iteration, to $n$, then $c$ is the sum of 1 to $n$ over $c$?

Comment: @anothercoderbro The condition is $\sum\limits_{x=1}^n \frac{x}c=1\Rightarrow  \frac{1}c\sum\limits_{x=1}^n x=1\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{x=1}^n x=c$